# slideup and slidedown with damper effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, visual-effects

Is there a jQuery add on that has `slideUp` and `slideDown` effects with damper effect? That is, the change of size starts with a rather quick speed, and slows down towards the end of the movement.

Comment: this will be a handy page for you. http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in an easing to use as a second argument...

```
$("#something").slideDown(500, "linear");
```

jQuery includes `swing` and `linear`, with the former being the default.

To get the behaviour you describe, use `easeOut`, which is available in jQuery UI (which you've tagged the question).

Comment: `slideDown` does not seem to interpret the second argument as easing, but I figured out that I can use something like `animate({height: 'show'}, 500, 'easeOutExpo')` using jquery.easing.